# ValueInjecter : Inject child property independently into destination

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, valueinjecter

Consider I have the below classes:

```
class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Child MyChild { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my Main() method:

```
Child MyChild = new Child() { Name = "Tom" };
Destination dest = new Destination() { Id = 101 };
dest.InjectFrom(MyChild);  // THIS DOESN'T INJECT AND ASSIGN THE OBJECT TO THE Destination.MyChild property.
```

So I wish to separately map/inject an object to a destination property. Can someone guide me on that.

Comment: it doesn't work because InjectFrom takes properties from source object and inject them into destination object. you are not doing so.

Comment: That's what I don't want. What I want is the object itself to be injected as a property of the destination; using the same name and type convention. Does ValueInjecter provide such a functionality ?

Comment: if dest.MyChild is not null do: dest.MyChildis.InjectFrom(MyChild)

Comment: I can't use that. MyChild will always be null & I want it to be injected rather than being mapped. My design expects it to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

ValueInjecter project is just a kind of mapping project.
InjectFrom takes properties from source object and inject them into destination object.

> What I want is the object itself...

I believe you want a shallow/deep prototype copy. otherwise you should inject the instance...

you can implements some of ValueInjecter API to solve your problem however, if you do so then your model will bound to technology. you will have to do it over and over again. so it seems a bad idea.

I'd like to offer you an alternative solution:

```
    public static T InjectClone<T>(this T source)
    {
    //note: you have to implements HasCopyConstractor & HasDefualtConstractor...

        if (source is ICloneable)
            return (T) ((ICloneable) source).Clone();

        var type = source.GetType();

        if (HasCopyConstractor(type))
            return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type, source);

        if (HasDefualtConstractor(type))
        {
            var target = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType());

            target.InjectFrom(source);

            return target;
        }

        throw new exception.....
    }

    public static T InjectTo<T>(this T source, ref T target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            target = source.InjectClone();
        }
        else
        {
            target.InjectFrom(source);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

now you can achieve your goal with:

```
dest.MyChild = MyChild.InjectClone();
```

InjectTo is an option if dest.MyChild won't be a property:

```
MyChild.InjectTo(ref dest.MyChild);
```